# Vue Js Search Filter goes wrong when using pagination

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, pagination

I am developing Single Page Blog Application using Laravel + Vue. now I added the pagination in the application based on Laravel pagination data which is return in API. All work fine
but the problem is when I filter data or user search for any keyword that matches the title of the blog will be returned.

So when the user is on the 3rd page of pagination and searches for some keyword and if that keyword data was on the first page then the result will show "NO DATA FOUND".

But if the user was on the first page and search for a query that exists in the current page then shows "DATA FOUND"

Here is my filter code

```
computed:{
    filteredBlog: function(){
        if(this.searchQ){
            return this.blogData.filter((blog) => {
                return blog.title.toLowerCase().match(this.searchQ.toLowerCase());
            })
        }else{
            return this.blogData;
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshots :

[Currently, I'm on the 3rd page of pagination So Data not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1tsR.png)

[Now I am on 1st page so data found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP2jN.png)

Comment: this is because your collection does not have the data. you have to make a request to laravel to get specific data.

Comment: `the problem is when I filter data or user search for any keyword that match to title of blog will be returned.`
Hi, can you rephrase this? It's difficult to understand the problem you're describing.

Comment: @SoyChai When user search for 'javas` as shown in first image it didnt retrive data but when user is on first page and search for `javas` than they found data

Comment: As a user stated before, you are getting your information but each page's DATA, not all data (and that is good), your problem is that you are confusing each page's DATA with a "local" filter, so when you filter, you are looking at the current data you have, you are not asking Laravel (DB) where is that if it exists... so you have to do an AJAX call and ask your Backend for that data and then go to the page you want or show the info... Right now you are only filtering your current page's data.